# Is this inequality true? If yes, for what functions?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $B=B(0,1)\subset \mathbb R^2$. Let $u$ be a radially symmetric differentiable function on $B$ and $v=Ax+b$ be a linear function where $A$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix satisfies $A=-A^T$, and $b=(b_1,b_2)$ is any constant.

Define for $a=(a_1,a_2)\in\mathbb R^2$, $|a|=\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2}$.

I want to prove
$$
\int_B |\nabla u|\,dx\leq \int_B|\nabla u-Ax-b|\,dx. \tag 1
$$
I think this inequality probability is not true but I can not find a counterexample...

Please help me to find a counterexample and if possible, what kind of assumptions should I add to $u$ so that equation $(1)$ is true?

Thank you!

Comment: Hmm... for $L_2$ norms it is true.

Comment: @A.G. There is a reason I ask the $L^1$ norm. :)

Comment: I guess so ;) I will bet on a counterexample. $L_1$ norms are nasty.

Comment: @A.G. I tried to let $A\equiv 0$ but it does not work.

Comment: It would help if you put in the question what had you tried so far. Did you mean you *proved* it is true for $A=0$ or you did not manage to finish disproving?

Comment: @A.G. Sorry I deleted the line which makes the confusion...

Comment: The $\lvert\,\cdot\,\rvert$ in the integral is the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes it is. Updated.

Comment: Okay, so $\nabla u(x)$ is always parallel to $x$ while $Ax$ is orthogonal to $x$. For $b = 0$, that immediately yields the inequality. No idea whether it helps anything in the general case, though.

Comment: @DanielFischer I think having $b\neq 0$ might be important since it shift function and can make it larger or smaller...

Comment: Note that since the vector fields $A\vec{x}$ and $\vec{\nabla}u$ are rotationally symmetric about the origin, we can change our coordinates to ones in which $b_2 = 0$ (or $b_1 = 0$, if you prefer.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Of course, I noticed. I am now trying to construct a counterexample with $b=[0,1]$.

Comment: I don't think you will find a counterexample. I believe the inequality is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was sceptical at the beginning, but the formula turns out to be true at the end. Here is the $n$-dimensional variant.

Let $N$ denote the outer unit normal for the sphere $S_r=\{|x|=r\}$, $0<r\le 1$. We have
$$
\int_{S_r}|\nabla u|\,ds_r=\left|\int_{S_r}\nabla u\cdot N\,ds_r\right|=
\left|\int_{S_r}(\nabla u+Ax+b)\cdot N\,ds_r\right|\le\int_{S_r}|\nabla u+Ax+b|\,ds_r.
$$
Here we used that $Ax\bot N$ and the flux of the constant field $b$ over the sphere is zero (from the divergence theorem since $b^Tx$ is harmonic or can be seen directly). Finally, the integration wrt $r$ from $0$ to $1$ gives
$$
\int_B|\nabla u|\,dx\le\int_B|\nabla u+Ax+b|\,dx.
$$

**Generalization:** for any harmonic function $v$ and for any vector field $F(x)\bot x$ in the unit ball $B$ we have
$$
\int_B|\nabla u|\,dx\le\int_B|\nabla u+F(x)+\nabla v|\,dx.
$$

Comment: $Ax\bot N$ because $A=-A^T$ I think?

Comment: @Denoising Right! $x^TAx=(x^TAx)^T=x^TA^Tx=-x^TAx$ $\Rightarrow$ $x^TAx=0$. Also $N\parallel x$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $u$ is radially symmetric, we can write $u(x) = f(\lvert x\rvert)$ with $f \colon [0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$, and since $u$ is assumed differentiable, $f$ must be differentiable too. Let's assume that $f$ is continuously differentiable for simplicity.

For every $x \neq 0$, we can write

$$b = \underbrace{\frac{\langle b, x\rangle}{\lvert x\rvert^2}\cdot x}_{p(x)} + w(x)$$

with $w(x) \perp x$. Then we can split

$$v(x) = \nabla u(x) - Ax - b = (\nabla u(x) - p(x)) - (Ax + w(x)).$$

Since $(Ax + w(x)) \perp (\nabla u(x) - p(x))$, we have

$$\lvert \nabla u(x) - p(x)\rvert \leqslant \lvert \nabla u(x) - Ax - b\rvert.\tag{1}$$

Now, for $0 \leqslant \varphi < \pi$, look at

$$\int_{-1}^1 \lvert\nabla u(t\cdot e_\varphi) - p (t\cdot e_\varphi)\rvert\,dt,$$

where $e_\varphi = (\cos \varphi, \sin \varphi)$. Let us fix $\varphi$ and write $g(t) = \nabla u(t\cdot e_\varphi),\; h(t) = p(t\cdot e_\varphi)$ for $t\in (-1,1)$ for a shorter notation. Since

$$\nabla u(x) = \frac{f'(\lvert x\rvert)}{\lvert x\rvert}\cdot x$$

we have $g(-t) = -g(t)$. And we have $h(-t) = h(t)$, so

$$\langle g(t),h(t)\rangle > 0 \iff \langle g(-t),h(-t)\rangle < 0.$$

Hence

\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^1 \lvert g(t) - h(t)\rvert\,dt
&= \int_0^1 \lvert g(t) - h(t)\rvert + \lvert g(-t) - h(-t)\rvert\,dt\\
&= \int_0^1 \bigl\lvert\lvert g(t)\rvert \pm \lvert h(t)\rvert\bigr\rvert + \bigl\lvert\lvert g(-t)\rvert \mp \lvert h(-t)\rvert\bigr\rvert\,dt\\
&\geqslant \int_0^1 \lvert g(t)\rvert \pm \lvert h(t)\rvert + \lvert g(-t)\rvert \mp \lvert h(-t)\rvert\,dt\\
&= \int_0^1 \lvert g(t)\rvert + \lvert g(-t)\rvert\,dt\\
&= \int_{-1}^1 \lvert g(t)\rvert\,dt,
\end{align}

so we see

$$\int_B \lvert \nabla u(x) - p(x)\rvert\,dx \geqslant \int_B \lvert \nabla u(x)\rvert\,dx,$$

which together with $(1)$ proves the desired inequality.

Comment: will have a very careful look tonight. Thank you so much for answering!

Comment: I have changed things to be more readable (I think).

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer, but I'm out of time to work on it further just now, and so I'm putting it up in hopes that someone will be able to fill in the missing step in the comments.  It's ugly and coordinate-based, and it's only got a physicist's level of rigor;  but I suspect that the inequality is in fact true.  The one missing step is in boldface below.

---

As noted in the comments, we can choose coordinates such that $\vec{b} = (b,0)$.  We can also write 
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & a \\ -a & 0 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
In polar coordinates $\{r, \theta\}$, the vectors in question are then
$$
\vec{\nabla} u = \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} \hat{r}, \qquad A \vec{x} = a r \hat{\theta}, \qquad \vec{b} = b (\cos \theta \hat{r} - \sin \theta \hat{\theta}).
$$
Brute-forcing the integrand, then, we have after some algebra
\begin{align}
I \equiv \left| \vec{\nabla} u - A \vec{x} - \vec{b} \right| &= \left[ \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} \right)^2 + b^2 + a^2 r^2 - 2 b \left( \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} \right) \cos \theta + a r \sin \theta  \right)\right]^{1/2} \\
&= \left[ C^2 + b^2  - 2 b C \cos (\theta - \theta_0)\right]^{1/2}
\end{align}
where 
$$
C^2 = \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} \right)^2 + a^2 r^2
$$
and $\theta_0$ is determined in terms of the above quantities as well.  (It will turn out to be unimportant in just a second.)
This will need to be integrated over $r \in [0,1]$ and $\theta \in [0, 2\pi]$.  In particular, when we do the integral with respect to $\theta$, we get
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} I \, d\theta = \int_{\theta_0}^{\theta_0 + 2 \pi} \left[ C^2 + b^2  - 2 b C \cos (\theta - \theta_0) \right]^{1/2} \, d \theta = \int_{0}^{ 2 \pi} \left[ C^2 + b^2  - 2 b C \cos \theta' \right]^{1/2} d\theta'
$$
(using the periodicity of the integrand in the first step and defining $\theta' = \theta - \theta_0$ in the second.

This latter integral can be expressed in terms of complete elliptic integral of the second kind:
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} I \, d\theta = 4 |C - b| \, E \left( - \frac{4 b C}{(C- b)^2} \right).
$$
**It would therefore suffice to prove that this quantity is greater than $2 \pi |C|$ for all values of $b$;**  if this were true, then we would have
$$ 
\int_0^{2\pi} I \, d\theta \geq \int_0^{2\pi} |C| \, d \theta \geq \int_0^{2\pi} \left| \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} \right| \, d \theta,
$$
and integrating both sides with respect to $r$ would yield the desired inequality.  Equality would hold only when $a = b = 0$.